# Rails stream audio mp3 from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, audio-streaming

I'm building an app that has mp3 files stored on Amazon S3, and want to allow users to listen to the audio files from their browsers.

The original plan was to use the html5 audio tag, but since that won't work in older browsers, an alternative is needed.

I've never worked with streaming audio before, and don't know what is needed to get started. Do I need to use an outside player to do this? Can it be done in html? Javascript? What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML5 as the main solution and fall back to javascript or flash if it is not supported. Something like this might work well: http://jplayer.org/